# DB::connection() Laravel 5 not working

Tags: postgresql, laravel, laravel-5

I'am using Laravel 5.0 and I make 2 database which is one for system and two for data. when I try to change connection to get data from my second database it tell error

> SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "barang" does not
>   exist LINE 1: select * from barang

Here my Controller

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;

class MultiController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $data = DB::connection('pgsql2')->select('select * from barang');

        return view('laporan.db')->withData($data);
    }
```

Database.php

```
<?php

return [

    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

    'default' => 'pgsql',

    'connections' => [

        'pgsql' => [
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'larasimak'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'postgres'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'postgres'),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
        ],

        'pgsql2' => [
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'simkie_data'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'postgres'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'postgres'),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
        ],
```

my DotEnv

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=nlXoLNFcWAD9rtTGXCUSpDdbQxms1ADi

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=larasimak
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=postgres

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the credential of second database. Current both database are using same credential. Try following for second database:

> database.php

```
 'pgsql2' => [
        'driver'   => 'pgsql',
        'host'     => env('PS2_DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database' => env('PS2_DB_DATABASE', 'simkie_data'),
        'username' => env('PS2_DB_USERNAME', 'postgres'),
        'password' => env('PS2_DB_PASSWORD', 'postgres'),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
        'schema'   => 'public',
    ]
```

> .evn

```
PS2_DB_HOST=localhost
PS2_DB_DATABASE=simkie_data
PS2_DB_USERNAME=postgres
PS2_DB_PASSWORD=postgres
```